# UIButton center moves back to default position after returning from a segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have a button that does animations and the position updates accordingly using `setCenter` but after I segue to a new view controller and then return back to the previous view controller (the one holding the button) the button's center gets set back to default. I don't have any constraints on the button and I try and set the center of the button again in the `viewWillAppear` method but I'm not having any luck. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

This is within an IBAction where the button moves along the y axis

```
if (!helpViewHidden)
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.75 animations:^{
        self.login.center = CGPointMake([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width/2, self.helpButton.frame.origin.y + 100.0);
    } completion:nil];
}
else
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.75 animations:^{
        self.login.center = CGPointMake([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width/2, self.helpView.frame.origin.y + 120.0);
    } completion:nil];
}

helpViewHidden = !helpViewHidden;
```

And here's the `viewWillAppear` method

Obviously `self.login` is my issue.

```
[self.login setCenter:CGPointMake([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width/2, self.helpButton.bounds.origin.y + 100)];
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you turned off auto layout, the system will add constraints to any view you make in IB. If you change the position of an object by setting frames, the auto layout system will cause that view to revert to its constraint determined position when the view gets redrawn. So, you either need to turn off auto layout, or change the button's position by manipulating its constraints. The easiest way to do this is to make an IBOutlet to the constraint you need to change, and change its constant value in code.